# Mock Oracle CallableStatement.getCursor()

Tags: java, unit-testing

I'm dealing with an Oracle 10g database and the following stored procedure is provided:

```
 procedure get_synopsis (
   p_id in  my_schema.products.p_id%type,
   p_synopses out sys_refcursor);  -- cursor of - synopsis_type, synopsis_text
```

In my Java code I prepare the statement in this way:

```
String idForDb = fromIdUrlToIdDb(prodIdUrl); 
statement.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.VARCHAR);
statement.setString(1, idForDb );
statement.registerOutParameter(2, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
```

And I get the data I need in this way:

```
String defaultSyn, nonDefSyn;

String returnedId = ((OracleCallableStatement)stm).getString(1);
try ( ResultSet synopses = ((OracleCallableStatement)stm).getCursor(2) ){ // p_synopses - cursor of: synopsis_type, synopsis_text

    while( synopses!=null && synopses.next() ){

        String type = synopses.getString(1) != null ? synopses.getString(1).toUpperCase() : null;

        if( type != null ){

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( synopses.getClob(2).getCharacterStream() );
            String line;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
               sb.append(line).append("\n");
            }

            if("DEFAULT".equals(type)){
                defaultSyn = sb.toString();
            }else if("NONDEFAULT".equals(type)){
                nonDefSyn = sb.toString();
            }

            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

**In my tests how can I mock *(OracleCallableStatement)stm.getCursor(2)*?**

I'm trying with org.jmock.Mockery but without success:

```
Mockery mockery_inner = new Mockery();
final ResultSet mocked_resultset = mockery_inner.mock(ResultSet.class);
mockery_inner.checking(new Expectations() {{
    allowing(mocked_resultset).getString(1); will(returnValue("TEST_SYNOPSES-TYPE"));
    allowing(mocked_resultset).getClob(2); will(returnValue("TEST_CLOooooooB"));
}});

Mockery mockery = new Mockery();
final CallableStatement statement = mockery.mock(CallableStatement.class);

mockery.checking(new Expectations() {{
    allowing(statement).getString(1); will(returnValue("TEST_RETURNED-PROD-ID"));
    allowing(statement).getCursor(2); will(returnValue(mocked_resultset));  // cannot find symbol getCursor(int). Location: interface java.sql.CallableStatement
}});
```

Reason clearly is: *cannot find symbol getCursor(int). Location: interface java.sql.CallableStatement*.

If I try *allowing((OracleCallableStatement)statement).getCursor(2)* I get "java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy6 cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement". Note: OracleCallableStatement is not an interface and thus cannot be mocked with Mockery.

I'm trying to use a "manual" mock but I'm having problems creating an instance..

```
class MockOracleCallableStatement implements OracleCallableStatement {

    ResultSet mocked_resultset;

    public MockOracleCallableStatement(){

        Mockery mockery_inner = new Mockery();
        mocked_resultset = mockery_inner.mock(ResultSet.class);
        mockery_inner.checking(new Expectations() {{
            allowing(mocked_resultset).getString(1); will(returnValue("DEFAULT")); // will pick value from an array
            allowing(mocked_resultset).getClob(2); will(returnValue("TEST_CLOooooooooooB"));
        }});
    }

    @Override
    ResultSet getCursor(int paramIndex) throws SQLException{
        return mocked_resultset;
    }
    @Override
    String getString(int paramIndex) throws SQLException{
        return "mockedGetString1--test";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a nutshell, **DON'T**.

Mocking JDBC (along with a lot of other things) is a fools errand and will not test the things you think it's testing but will cost you a huge amount of time.

You should really write an integration test that actually goes to your database.  This is the only way to verify your database code is correct.  If you can, use the exact same version of the database as you do in production, if not use an in-memory database like H2*.

I wrote an [article for JAX magazine](https://jaxenter.com/testing-the-database-layer-119366.html) on this exact subject which will go into much more detail.

- Although this has other issues due to compatibility

Comment: We already have integration tests in place. I need this unit test just to test if the response is correctly serialized into the expected JSON. Could probably use with some refactoring to separate those functionalities then. Thanks

Comment: @Ga Sacchi If you're aiming for a 100% unit test coverage, you might find it difficult to meet this goal. However, I agreed your particular problem is probably caused by too much logic in data access tier. You could create a separate class and only mock ’synopses’ ResultSet object.

Comment: In that case, have your data access layer return you an object which you own and control and run your integration tests against that.  You can then separately test that the Json conversion happens correctly from that object.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like I can use [Mockito](http://mockito.org/)..

```
OracleCallableStatement oraCSMock = Mockito.mock(OracleCallableStatement.class);
```

**UPDATE**:
The method *CLOB.getDBAccess(connection)* is a static method of the CLOB class and as such cannot be mocked with Mockito.
(You can mock statics with [Powermock](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockStatic)).

I ended up testing just the 404 case then:

```
ResultSet mocked_resultset = Mockito.mock(ResultSet.class);

doReturn( null ) // cant' use "DEFAULT" since getClob() will throw npe anyway. Will test just 404 then.
.when(mocked_resultset).getString(1);

doReturn( false )
.when(mocked_resultset).next(); // or just return null in getCursor(2)


OracleCallableStatement statement = Mockito.mock(OracleCallableStatement.class);

doReturn( "testID" )
.when( statement ).getString(1);

doReturn( mocked_resultset )
.when( statement ).getCursor(2);
```